# SQL count number of observations that are at the minimum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table:

```
    yr      mo    user   visits
    2015    11    A       3
    2015    11    A       3 
    2015    11    B       4    
    2015    11    B       4   
    2015    11    B       4
    2015    11    C       3
    2015    12    A       6
    2015    12    A       2
    2015    12    B       1
    2015    12    C       6
```

I need aggregate it to:

```
     yr    mo   visitor min  max  cntmin  cntmax
    2015   11    3       3     4     2       1
    2015   12    3       1     6     1       2
```

Where vistor is the number of unique visitors per month, min is the minimum visits over users per month, max is the maximum user per month, cntmin and cnt max are the number of users that were at the minimum and maximum (respectively).

I have all the columns in the aggregated table except for the cntmin and cntmax. I cannot seem to figure out how to get to them. Any help at all would be appreciated. I am using tansact sql.

Comment: Show us what query have you try it?

Comment: Can you explain about ctmin? for `2015, 11` the value is `ctmin = 2` because `user=A` has visits 3 (min) twice? But `ctmax  = 1` and `B` has 4 (max) visit three times

Comment: ctmin is the # of users that achieved the minimum - ie. the minimum vists for  2015, 11 is 3 and users A and C both achieved the min. the min. so its 2. Analogous for cntmax.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using two levels of aggregation:

```
select yr, mo, count(*) as numusers, minminv, maxmaxv,
       sum(case when minv = minminv then 1 else 0 end) as numAtMin,
       sum(case when maxv = maxmaxv then 1 else 0 end) as numAtMax
from (select yr, mo, [user], min(visits) as minv, max(visits) as maxv,
             min(min(visits)) over (partition by yr, mo) as minminv,
             max(max(visits)) over (partition by yr, mo) as maxmaxv
      from t
      group by yr, mo, [user]
     ) ymu
group by yr, mo, minminv, maxmaxv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (old and incorrect):

```
SELECT yr, mo, COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS visitor
   , MIN(visits) AS min 
   , MAX(visits) AS max 
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN visits = MIN(visits) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cntMin 
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN visits = MAX(visits) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cntMax
FROM TableName
GROUP BY yr, mo
```

New (post-advice):

```
SELECT A.yr, A.mo, A.visitor, A.min, A.max
, (SELECT B.yr, B.mo, COUNT(B.visits) FROM TableName AS B WHERE B.yr = A.yr AND B.mo = A.mo AND B.visits = A.min GROUP BY B.yr, B.mo) AS cntMin
, (SELECT C.yr, C.mo, COUNT(C.visits) FROM TableName AS C WHERE C.yr = A.yr AND C.mo = A.mo AND C.visits = A.max GROUP BY C.yr, C.mo) AS cntMax
FROM 
(SELECT TableName.yr, TableName.mo, COUNT(DISTINCT TableName.user) AS visitor
   , MIN(visits) AS min 
   , MAX(visits) AS max 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY yr, mo) AS A
```

Comment: You can't mix aggregated and non aggregated column references like that.

Comment: @Martin Smith, thanks!  If only this worked, that'd be swell.  I'll have to edit with a nested subquery...

Comment: This is what I was trying originally - it returns an error: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I forgot the GROUP BY clauses in the subqueries.  Try the newly edited version if you like!